# Добавить кнопку "Сначала искать"

Tags: предложение, поиск

Автоматический поиск это круто и современно. Но почему бы не дать пользователю самому принимать решение, о том, что именно сейчас, в данный момент, нужно выполнить поиск. Голосую за то, чтоб добавить кнопку "Сначала искать".

Что касается автоматического поиска, наилучшим вариантом мне представляется начинать его, когда в поле "Тема" после 15-ти введенных выполняется одно из условий:

1. был утерян фокус
2. был введен пробельный символ
3. был введен знак препинания

Но самое главное - верните кнопку "Сначала искать"! )

Comment: Зачем? Это же не поиск. Для поиска есть поле наверху.

Comment: Зачем? Объясню. Я ленивый новичок, зашедший на сайт. Я решил сразу создать тему, которая уже миллион раз поднималась, но кнопка "сначала искать" прямо у меня перед глазами. Я гораздо чаще нажму эту кнопку, чем стану задумываться о том, что для поиска есть "специальное поле". Я кстати, уже на этом ресурсе добрых месяца два и ни разу не пользовался поиском в верхнем окне. Потому что для меня он выглядит заимствованным вариантом, который использовал ленивый разраб, чтоб не делать нормальный поиск. Просто говорю о впечатлении.

Comment: Кстати, это мне приснилось, или кнопка "сначала искать" изначально была?

Comment: @Razzwan вы имеете в виду кнопку при создании вопроса? Насколько я помню, сначала поискать на сайте предлагается только незарегистрированным пользователям, либо только на первом вопросе.

Comment: Тем более, т.е. сначала приучили пользователя к этой кнопке, а потом отобрали ее. (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Вариант 1

Пишите текст поискового запроса в текстовое поле в верхнем правом углу экрана. В поиске работают разные дополнительные параметры, о них есть [раздел справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жмите кнопку «искать», на фото она в центре =)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Вариант 2

Сразу переходите на страницу поиска, например по закладке:

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: Есть ещё "вариант 3" с [google://site:ru.stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aru.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @Discord отличный вариант, кстати.

Comment: Зачем мне два раза вводить одно и то же? Сначала в строке поиска, а потом в строке заголовка темы, если можно все это сделать в одной строке? Я ленив. Да и не только я. Просто даже на русскоязычном форуме возникает очень много дублированных вопросов. Старожилы жалуются, а при этом новичек не находит нужное ему, когда сразу вводит название темы. Я сейчас себя имею в виду.